# Should we use a standard response about sticking to defaults for mathematical typography?

Tags: discussion, answers, policy, typography

Questioners often ask how they can tinker with typography (particularly in math mode, particularly white space). In many cases the best answer is "Please don't - the defaults have been carefully chosen to implement proven best practices." Here's an example, with a comment to that effect, and a good response from the OP: [Is there a way to define single space or more in math mode to be \,?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94697/is-there-a-way-to-define-single-space-or-more-in-math-mode-to-be).

Should this site have a standard polite response to post for those questions?

Related: [What should the policy be on typography/design questions?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/679/what-should-the-policy-be-on-typography-design-questions)

Comment: I think it's perfectly ok to suggest _not_ to do something, but don't see why there should be an issue to providing a solution to something, even if the general consensus is that one should not do it. There are particular circumstances, which are not always clear in the MWE in the question where it may make sense. Not every use of LaTeX is intended for a paper in a professional journal so let the user decide if they still want to do what they asked.

Comment: Even if they *were* publishing a paper in a professional journal, they could still be better off tweaking the odd equation here and there. LaTeX doesn't always get it 'right', that's the point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's perfectly ok to suggest not to do something, but don't see why there should be an issue to providing a solution to something, even if the general consensus is that one should not do it. There are particular circumstances, which are not always clear in the MWE in the question where it may make sense. Not every use of LaTeX is intended for a paper in a professional journal so let the user decide if they still want to do what they asked.

Comment: Converted comment to answer, based on the number of upvotes on my comment, and that no other answer has surfaced.