# Deciding which typography answer should be accepted?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, accepting

Should I accept the answer that is favored by my personal taste?

I am asking typography questions when I don't know what the right answer is (e.g. [Spacing in "$d=2$-dimensional"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504351/spacing-in-d-2-dimensional) )
So maybe my own taste shouldn't be the deciding factor?

Would it be more scientific to wait for some votes and comments, so that I can try to accept an answer that captures the taste of the majority? (How long should I wait, for example in [Spacing in "$d=2$-dimensional"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504351/spacing-in-d-2-dimensional) would you already accept a solution?)

I think references (like "in Knuth's textbook this typography is used") should be considered very strongly in choosing which answer to accept. But should I wait until such a references are provided before I accept an answer?

<sub>(PS: I think it is very important to allow users to ask mathematics-related and TeX-related typography questions on this site, because there is a large demand for it; see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/701/128042 or https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6651/128042. I think the purpose of Stack Exchange is to help people and not to collect points. Therefore I do NOT want this post to start a discussion against typography questions in general.)</sub>

Comment: There is no better answer. You have a problem and you accept the one that best solves your problem according to your idea. This does not make it the best.

Comment: ...we are all about typography here, so I don't understand your concern in the closing postscript. Is it necessary?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Either

- select the answer that benefits the *community* the most (according to your opinion), hoping that future visitors to your question will find meaning in your choice; or
- select the answer that helped *you* most (based on your situation). Users who visit your post in the future should use their own judgement (and voting) to corroborate choices or find something better from the answer without the check mark.

Ultimately, the choice is *yours*.

Comment: Or, if the answers you get are equally good, don't accept an answer. Although we like to have accepted answers, I don't think that every question *must* have an accepted answer.